# Scapy Routing Table

Tags: python-2.7, scapy

Caution this is for testing purposes.

I have a script that creates multiple DNS query from a spoofed subnet; however i'm having issues with using Scapy routing table: conf.route. I went through the scapy documentation, but it doesn't show how to implement the scapy routing table.

```
from scapy.all import *

file = open('/opt/scripts/ip.txt', 'r').readlines() 
for line in file:
    lines = line.rstrip()
    for x in range (0, 8000):
        answer = send(IP(src='9.0.0.0/30', dst=(lines))/UDP(dport=53)/DNS(rd=3,qd=DNSQR(qname="nih.gov"+str(x))),verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this issue:
        #conf.route.add(host=(y.y.y.y), gw="x.x.x.x")

What this does it actually adds a temporary entry in the routing table for the lifespan of the script, once the script ends it will remove the temporary route from the routing table.